# Login loop after installing amd driver

Tags: drivers, login, amdgpu-pro

After I installed amdgpu pro and reboot I cannot login to my pc. It's stuck in login screen forever. I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd>, it says

```
amdgpu-core not installed, use --fix-broken install.
```

That doesn't work, it says it only can be installed on Ubuntu 18.04. What to do now?

Comment: Can you login under `tty3`? After you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd>? If you can login, try running `sudo apt install --fix-broken`

Comment: Not work , it's said the package only can install at 18.04

Answer (score 0):

go to a package manager, like Muon, and mark the BROKEN libraries for removal. Works only with some package manager, don't know why.

Still haven't figured out how to run amdgpu-pro in Cosmic Cuttlefish (18.10).

Regards,
Boki

Comment: Thx but I cannot boot to gui , I only can  use command line